# Using Destructor in inheritance

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, destructor

In this inheritance program I create 2 classes which A is parent and B is child class . and i crate cons of both classes and also use
Destructor, and both classes have tow objects . @ MY question is that
when  my program is run then its output show 2 Destructor  of class a
why ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A  
{
    int a;

public:
    A(int a1)   // cons(A)
    {
        a = a1;
    }
    A() {}   // Dis(A)
    ~A() { cout << "A Disturctor"<< endl; }
};
class B : public A   // inheritance 
{
    int b;

public:
    B(int b1)  // cons (A)
    {
        b = b1;
    } 
    ~B() { cout << "B Disturctor" << endl; }    // Dis(B)
   
};

int main()
{
    A hamza(1);
    B Ramza(4);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
B Disturctor 

A Disturctor1 

A Disturctor2
```

Comment: Remember that inheritance is an ***is-a*** relationship. The class `B` *is an* `A`. If you add output in the `A` default constructor as well, you will see two `A` object being created. Then remove the `hamza` object from the `main` function and see that both `A` and `B` will have one constructor and one destructor each.

Comment: It may may more sense if you instrument *all* the ctors and dtors. You'll see that part of constructing a B is constructing its A roots. Thus, so goes the opposite for a B's destruction.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  , yes both object are destroyed , but why destructor of class A is invoke 2 times why? –

Comment: Because you have *two* `A` objects. `Ramza` is *both* an `A` and a `B` object. Since `B` is both `B` and `A`, both destructors must be invoked. [Here's your code](https://godbolt.org/z/8bjM61q6b) (simplified and with added output in constructor as well). That should hopefully make you understand it better.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : Means `Ramza` is inherited on both classes .  `Class A` ,     `Class B` !

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : And when destructor is called then  both `Ramza` are destroy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first "A Disturctor" is for object "A hamza(1)".
The second "A Disturctor" is for object "B Ramza(4)"

Since B inherits from A, when object of class B is destroyed, destructor of both class B and class A are called.

Comment: yes both object are destroyed , but why destructor  of class A is invoke 2 times ?

Comment: @Hamza • the destructor is invoked for object `Ramza`.  Then the destructor is invoked for `hamza`.  Two objects.  Two destructors.